# how can I get better performance here?

Tags: python, graphics, project, conways-game-of-life

I am working on a project to visualize the game of life and it's different variations.

Smoothlife is the most complicated, I am not quit sure if I am doing it 100% right, but however any suggestions to increase the performance here??

what about FFT and kernel convolution any one who knows the proper way to create the kernel??

attaching a link to the article of smooth life

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.1567.pdf

here's a version implemented by Sean Murhpy, but can't really get my head around the math.

https://github.com/duckythescientist/SmoothLife

```
from cmath import sqrt
from concurrent.futures import thread
import os
import numpy as np
import threading
from turtle import shape

class SmoothL:

    def __init__(self,width, height, inner_radius=2, outer_radius=10):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.inner = inner_radius
        self.outer = outer_radius
        self.game_field = np.zeros(shape=(self.width, self.height))
        self.game_field_next = np.zeros(shape=(self.width, self.height))
        self.inner_neigh = np.zeros(shape=(self.width, self.height))
        self.outer_neigh = np.zeros(shape=(self.width, self.height))
        self.b1 = 0.278
        self.b2 = 0.365
        self.d1 = 0.267
        self.d2 = 0.445
        self.n = 0.032
        self.m = 0.2
        
    def create_cells(self, new_cells, age):
        for i in range(new_cells):
            x = np.random.randint(0, self.width - self.outer)
            y = np.random.randint(0, self.height - self.outer)
            self.game_field[x:x + self.outer, y:y + self.outer] = age

    def sigmaoid_1(self, x, a):
        return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-4.0 * (x - a) / self.m))

    def sigmaoid_2(self, x, a, b):
        return self.sigmaoid_1(x, a) * (1.0 - self.sigmaoid_1(x, b))

    def sigmaoid_m(self, x, y, m):
        return x * (1.0-self.sigmaoid_1(m, 0.5)) + y * self.sigmaoid_1(m, 0.5)

    def sigmaoid_s(self, n, m):
        return self.sigmaoid_2(n, self.sigmaoid_m(self.b1, self.d1, m), self.sigmaoid_m(self.b2, self.d2, m))



    def get_neighbours(self,x,y):
        sum_outer = 0
        count_outer = 0
        sum_inner= 0
        count_inner = 0
        for k in range(-self.outer,self.outer+1):
            for h in range(-self.outer,self.outer+1):
                if 0<=x+k<self.width and 0<=y+h<self.height:
                    data=self.game_field[x+k][y+h]
                    if (float)(np.sqrt(k**2 + h**2))<=self.outer:
                        count_inner+=1
                        sum_inner+=data
                        if (float)(np.sqrt(k**2 + h**2))>self.inner:
                            count_outer+=1
                            sum_outer+=data
                            
        self.game_field_next[x][y]=np.clip(self.sigmaoid_s(sum_outer/count_outer,sum_inner/count_inner),0,1)

    def iterate_all(self,min_x,max_x,min_y,max_y):
        for i in range(min_x,max_x+1):
            for j in range(min_y,max_y+1):
                self.get_neighbours(i,j)
                

    def result(self,min_x,max_x,min_y,max_y):
        for i in range(min_x,max_x+1):
            for j in range(min_y,max_y+1):
                self.game_field[i][j]

    def next(self):
        threads= []
        y_range=(int)(self.height/10)
        min_y=0
        max_y=y_range-1

        x_range=(int)(self.width/10)
        min_x=0
        max_x=x_range-1

        for _ in range(10):
            min_y=0
            max_y=y_range-1
            for _ in range(10):
                t=threading.Thread(target=self.iterate_all,args=[min_x,max_x,min_y,max_y])
                t.start()
                threads.append(t)
                min_y+=y_range
                max_y+=y_range
            min_x+=x_range
            max_x+=x_range
      
        
        for thread in threads:
            thread.join()
            
        threads.clear()
         
        
        self.game_field=self.game_field_next
        return self.game_field
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.